# How can I extract selective data from a webpage using rvest?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have been trying to display the review rating of this song using rvest in r from [Pitchfork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v12Kg.png)https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/us-girls-heavy-light/ . In this case, it is 8.5. But somehow I get this:
[image]

Here is my code

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
library(tidyverse)

URL="https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/us-girls-heavy-light/"

webpage = read_html(URL)


cat("Review Rating")
webpage%>%
   html_nodes("div span")%>%
   html_text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can get the relevant information from the class of `div` which is `"score-circle"`.

```
library(rvest)

webpage %>% html_nodes('div.score-circle') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()
#[1] 8.5
```